# Splitting lines regular expression in Java

Tags: java, regex, split

I want to parse an almost program. The program is consisted of two lines and it is shown below:

```
java.io.*;
java.lang.*;
```

I am using a library, which reads the whole program and splits it using the command

```
String[] words = sourceCode.split("[\\s+|\\W+]");
```

What it is produced by that is the following

```
words[0] = "Java"
words[1] = "io"
words[2] = ""
words[3] = ""
words[4] = ""
words[5] = ""
words[6] = Java
words[7] = "lang"
words[8] = ""
words[9] = ""
words[10] = ""
words[11] = ""
```

However, What I want is to break that program in lines first, and after that at a line's component. That is, I am using

```
String[] allLines = file1String.split("[\n]");
String[][] wordsOfALine =new String[allLines.length][];
for (int i=0;i<allLines.length;i++){
       wordsOfALine[i] = allLines[i].split("[\\s+|\\W+]").clone();
}
```

However, what I am getting here is

```
wordsOfALine[0][0] = "Java"
wordsOfALine[0][1] = "io"
wordsOfALine[1][0] = "Java"
wordsOfALine[1][1] = "lang"
```

And therefore all the empty words have now disappeared. Do you know how I can bring them back? I need to be consistent with the library...

Thanks

Comment: I think I'd use a lexer rather than a regex for this, but that may only reflect my own biases...

Comment: You night want to read about what _character classes_ are.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, your split regex is a giant bug. This expression:

```
"[\\s+|\\W+]"
```

means any **single character** that is one of:

- whitespace
- the plus sign `+`
- the pipe char `|`
- a non-word char (which includes whitespace btw)

It should be just:

```
"\\W"
```

Also if you add an extra parameter to the split call (see [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) for why), you'll get trailing blank split terms.

This produces the output you want:

```
allLines[i].split("\\W", -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following and modify as needed.

```
String[] allLines = file1String.split("[\n]");
String[] wordsOfALine = {};
int k = 0;
for (int i=0 ;i<allLines.length;i++){
   String[] words= allLines[i].split("[\\r\\n]+]");
   for(int j = 0; j < lines.length; j++){
      wordsOfALine[k++] : " + words[j]);
   }
}
```